# Applying for an Ireland visa after refusal by the UK

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, ireland

I visited Ireland in May 2016 for a 7-day holiday and I left the country at the end of that week.

In February 2017, I applied for a UK visa to attend a conference and I was refused; the visa officer said I didn't state the site used to convert my salary into GBP. Also, they don't believe I have enough funds for the trip, and that I would depart the UK.

I have visited almost every part of the Schengen Area, as well as visiting Mexico, Malaysia, Thailand, the Philippines, and Turkey and I have never overstayed in any of these countries.

Now I want to visit Ireland again in June for a conference. I have to state on the visa application that I have been refused a UK visa. Will Ireland refuse to grant me a visa, as it shares information with the UK?

Comment: What was the visa that was refused for the UK and what is your nationality? Generally speaking data sharing means only that they share data, so while the officer in Ireland will be able to see details of your failed UK visa application, that doesn't mean you will be refused.